JSON Code based on date and priority
I want to create a due date column (calculated column) that is auto-populated using the date created and priority column, while excluding weekends.
In my priority column I have the following options:
1 = 1 day
2 = 5 days
3 = 20 days
4 = 20 days
7 = 1 day

Based off what date the item was created and the priority selected, I want the due date to auto-populate whilst excluding weekends and highlight the column in red if overdue.
I really don't know anything about JSON coding and would really appreciate a drafted formula for the above.

Did you already created a calculated column OR you need help with both calculated column formula and JSON column formatting for overdue dates?

I need help with both

I have created the calculated column but can only get it to count all days and not just work days ie Mon-Fri  =IF(Priority="1",Created+1,IF(Priority="2",Created+5,IF(Priority="3",Created+20,IF(Priority="4",Created+20,IF(Priority="7",Created+1)))))
